# TableCellRenderer works fine, table sorts fine, but doesn't repaint

Tags: java, swing, background, jtable

Here is my `JTable` mouse listener I've put it like this in table because I want it to sort directly.

```
myTable= new JTable();
myTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        if( myTable.getRowCount()!= 0) {
            TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter(myTable.getModel());
            myTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
            List<RowSorter.SortKey> date= new ArrayList<>();

            int columnIndexToSort = 10;
            datum.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(columnIndexToSort, SortOrder.DESCENDING));

            sorter.setSortKeys(date);
            sorter.sort();
        }
        myTable.repaint();
        myTable.revalidate();
    }
});
```

Here is the cell renderer which BTW, works nice but after sorting it doesn't repaint:

```
public class MyTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,int row,int col) {
    Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);

        Object resault = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 9);
        int value= Integer.parseInt(resault.toString()); 
        Color color = null;

        if (value>= 5000) {
            c.setBackground(new Color(144, 238, 144));
        }else if (value< 5000 && value>=500) {
            color = Color.ORANGE;
            c.setBackground(color);
        }else if (value>= 0 && value<500) {
            c.setBackground( new Color(255, 76, 76));
        }
            c.setFont(c.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
        return c;
    }
}
```

These are some of the things I've remembered to say about this particular problem if there is anything that is not understandable so I would get the answer please ask.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object resault = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 9);
```

The renderer shows the data in the view of the table. When you sort data the data in the TableModel is not changed, only the order of the data in the view.

So you should be using:

```
Object result = table.getValueAt(row, 9);
```

to get the data in the current view as it has been sorted.

Comment: this help'd, what happens is my type of date in database is bigint and its sorting but not sorting good it only catches month and day but year not. So i have sorting like this for example   01.01.17 / 02.01.2016

Comment: Then you need to convert the BigInt data to a real Date object and store the Date object in the TableModel. Or the other solution is to write a custom Comparator for the BigInt. Or better yet, don't store a Date as BigInt in the database. Store it as a Date.